# How can I mock db calls from dependent classes using gmock to test a function within a class?

Tags: googlemock

I am working on Unit Testing for an legacy code and I am new to gmock, so someone with gmock experience can you please help me here. The scenario to test is mentioned below, I need to test a function under class test3("test3.testFunction()").

I am not able to create an object for my class test3 because of db calls overhead as dependency. Calls like -> Inside test3 constructor, test2 instance gets called. Inside test2 constructor, test1 constructor gets called where there are some db calls.

Sample Code Snippet:

test1.h

```
class test1{
public:
    void initTest1()
    {
        //DBCalls
    }
};
```

test2.h

```
class test2
{
public:
    test2()
    {
        //test1 object creation.
        t1->initTest1();
    }

    test2 &getInstance(){
        //singleton instance of test2;
    }
};
```

test3.h

```
class test3
{
public:
    test3()
    {
        t2 = test2::getInstance();
    }

    void testFunction() {}
};
```

I need to mock all the db calls so I can test the test3.testFunction() without any trouble. I tried to mock the class test1 function "initTest1" using gmock. But even after mocking the test1.initTest1 as below and when I create an object for test3, test1::initTest1 gets invoked.

Mock Testing:

```
class MockTest1 : public test1
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, initTest1, ());
};
```

```
MockTest1 mk1;
EXPECT_CALL(mk1, initTest1()).Times(AnyNumber());

test3 t3;
```

I believe the above approach to mock is wrong. So could some one please guide me here. Is it possible to mock the db calls and can access test3.testFunction().